# Dilution solution

Tags: organic-chemistry

Please help me, I am a student.

Here is the question:
b)  You have a stock solution of 2 M HNO3  (nitric acid).   You need to prepare a 0.1M HNO3 solution.

(i)  What dilution do you need to do on the stock solution?

I think the fomulas for this question is:

volume of solution required to be diluted = concentration of solution you want / concentration of original solution  x volume of dilute solution you want.

But the questions did not give the volume of dilute solution wanted, so I could not work out this question.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to dilute it to 1/20th of its current strength so add 1ml of the stock soln to 19ml of water

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental concept at the core of dilution is conservation of matter. The amount of substance (number of moles) before and after the dilution is constant.

$$n_{1} = n_{2}$$

If you express the amount of substance in terms of solution concentration and volume, you have:

$$M_{1}V_{1} = M_{2}V_{2}$$

In your problem, what you have are values for $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$. That gives two unknowns, but you can solve for the ratio $\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}$. This provides the ratio of between the two volumes which is how much you need to dilute by.

Notice that the ratio between concentrations and ratio between volumes are inversely proportional. Since the concentration is 20 times smaller at the end of the dilution, the volume must be 20 times larger.